# React Material UI passing updated Date through Multi Page App

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I have created a multi page form and one of the pages that contains a datetime picker from material ui is not passing the updated date to the confirm page. I have created a sandbox. I have tried many methods including lifting the state, but none of it worked.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/inspiring-glade-74it3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have updated [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/inspiring-glade-74it3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) Please check it. You had lot of issue. You do `destructuring` props wrongly and again you put the `prefered_date` into a `values` objects. I cannot explain everything here instead, please check this fixing and read some `article on react`. You will have better understanding. Happy Learning :)

Comment: Hi Sorry @Khabir, I didn't see your updates on the sandbox. Is the link correct?

Comment: Yes that is the correct link and here I pasted it again https://codesandbox.io/embed/inspiring-glade-74it3